# How to use a function from another library in Numba for a Cuda GPU?

Tags: python, numba

I am new to numba, and I want to use md5 function from hashlib library in python on a CUDA GPU.

I have searched how to use external functions in my `@cuda.jit` function, but I didn't find anything useful, or any tutorial for it.
I have found in https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda-reference/host.html , that I can wrap my python function in a context to a thread but I really don't get it how to do it.

I want to use this function `result = hashlib.md5(str.encode())`
inside my code that will be run on the GPU.

Comment: You can't. Numba does not allow arbitrary Python code to run on the GPU

Comment: how about using jit with numba ? @talonmies

Comment: That is what my previous comment refers to. You cannot run arbitrary code inside @jit functions. Only a tiny subset of Python is supported. And no libraries

Comment: Okay ,Thanks @talonmies ,i do have one more question though if u may help me..does numba supports working with strings for CUDA? and if yes do you know any good documentation/tutorial for it? Thanks again.

Comment: No. Fixed length character arrays are supported. Strings are not